# how to call my dll and use it in powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell

I have my own `dll` which written in c#.
Now I want to call that from my `powershell` script.
I did the following;

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("E:\MyClass.dll")
$MyCompObj = New-Object MyClass.Student
```

But when I executing that, it giving me error
**Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type MyClass.Student**

Am I following a wrong way to do this??
Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your class has got constructors (at least one). So create the object with the good params

```
$MyCompObj = New-Object MyClass.Student -argumentlist "arg1","Arg2" ...
```