# how to send specific output value from exe (c#) to power shell script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

Now I'm creating a vsts build task, my approach is:

- Run powershell script
- Inside the powershell, I'll run the exe or dll
- Then use the output to extract the value.

My issue is:

- I do a lot of printing, and I'll print my value at the end and add
  some delimiter to be able to extract it
- but I feel like it's a bad design I'm not expert in powershell scripting but
- if anyone has a better design please let me know

Not sure if the script code helps but here it is

```
$psi = New-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo 
$psi.CreateNoWindow = $true 
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false 
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true 
$psi.RedirectStandardError = $true 
$psi.FileName = "app.exe"
$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process 
$process.StartInfo = $psi 
[void]$process.Start()
$output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() 
$process.WaitForExit() 
then process the output
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "My code works but could the design be better?" is off-topic for StackOverflow and on-topic for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The ability to run executables as commands is built into PowerShell. To run `app.exe` and capture its output, all you have to do is

```
$output = app.exe
```

PowerShell takes care of all the underlying process management.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more complex you can interop directly with the assembly, instead of using an EXE

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("E:\MyClass.dll")
$MyCompObj = New-Object MyClass.Student
```

See:
[how to call my dll and use it in powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17966056/194717)
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell